# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt, while reading CSV file using C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, desktop-application

I am trying to search data through a large CSV file (8MB) in size and has 18033 lines, which is a requirement for  Desktop Application using Windows Forms (C#) tried in .Net version 4 and 4.6.1.

the code for the function that I'm using is the following

```
private List<string> SearchData(string searchText)
    {
        try
        {
            List<string> dates = new List<string>();
            using (var csv = new FileStream(Config.DataPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(csv))
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
            {
                var lines = string.Empty;
                while ((lines = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (lines.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower()))
                    {
                        dates.Add(lines.Substring(0, 10));
                    }
                }
            }
            return dates;            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Unable to search the file");
            ex.Data.Add("SearchText", searchText);
            Logger.Log(ex, "SearchData");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But I'm getting the following exception

> System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Get the same exception while I am using File.ReadAllLines method as well. 
Have tried same code in VS2017 and VS 2019 in two different PC.

Odd about the error is if put a counter in the while loop it traverse upto 500 to 600 lines otherwise it traverses through the whole file and gives me exception at the end of the process. Also does not hit the catch even if I set the AccessViolationException. 
The code works fine in Linqpad, thus I am not sure whether the CSV file is corrupted or not.

If anyone has any idea that would be helpful. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest breaking the reads up into smaller pieces. Read x lines where x is some constant then start reading from y line where y is zero plus x times loop count, taking care not to read over the end.

Comment: A corrupted file should not cause any failure, except possibly an `InvalidDataException` thrown by a component actually trying to parse the data. You should never see an `AccessViolationException` from pure managed code. And the code you posted isn't even parsing the data, other than to detect line-breaks. 8MB is not large by modern standards. Bottom line: the most suspicious part of the incomplete code example you posted is the `Logger` class; i.e. there's probably some other exception occurring, but then when you try to log it, your buggy `Logger` class throws the `AccessViolationException`

Comment: By the way: there is no point in using `BufferedStream` with the `FileStream` class. The latter already has buffering built in.

Comment: Creating 18000 lowercased copies of the searchString isn't helpful either, although it shouldn't be the cause of any exceptions. When the exception is logged, does the logging include a stack trace?

Comment: @PeterDuniho-  Getting same error without logger as well, I have created blank project only with these lines and same is happening. Find the code for BufferedStream in another post, saying it might speed the process, although it is not helping.

Comment: Any other suggestion to read CSV file without using NPOI, OleDb (Access DB Engine) or SpreadsheetGear, would be helpful.

Comment: Did you look at the call stack of the exception?

Comment: No exception on my computer on some csv file.

Comment: @codelearner this code is *very* inefficient but won't throw an AccessViolationException. The file size is tiny. Post the *full* exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()`, including the call stack. This will show *where* the error occured and which method raised it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to take a look at the [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) library. Accordingly to the author,

> Reading records will yield results so only one record is in memory at a time.

This could avoid the memory problem that you are having.

Comment: The OP's exception has nothing to do with RAM usage. Besides, 8MB is a *tiny* amount of RAM. CsvHelper will avoid the inefficient reads and `ToLower()` conversions though

Comment: As he says that it's working well in Linkpad, I think that worth the test with another library.

Comment: Exceptions don't occur at random and the BCL isn't broken anyway. The OP isnt' using any library, just file IO and StreamReader. CsvHelper does the same

Comment: Find the issue and the solution as well. Although not sure how it is related. 
I had the following lines in the constructor of the form and I am using a customized font which was causing the problem. 
            `PrivateFontCollection privateFont = new PrivateFontCollection();
            privateFont.AddFontFile(Config.FontPath);
            this.Font = new Font(privateFont.Families[0], 12F);`
Removing the last line and setting the font to each control separately, solved the issue. Thank you all.